# Where's my error in proving $H_1(D^2,S^1) = 0$?

Tags: proof-verification, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

> Prove that $H_1(D^2, S^1) = 0$

I found that by the triple theorem there exists an exact sequence that contains:
$$\dots \rightarrow H_1(S^1) \rightarrow H_1(D^2) \rightarrow H_1(D^2,S^1) \rightarrow H_0(S^1) \rightarrow \dots $$

Where $H_1(D^2)=0$ since $D^2$ is closed and convex and $H_0(S^1) = \Bbb Z$ since $S^1$ is path-connected.

But then we have $0 \rightarrow H_1(D^2, S^1) \rightarrow \Bbb Z \rightarrow 0$, and since this is exact we must have the middle arrow as an isomorphism, which seems to show a contradiction.

What did I misunderstand here?

Comment: Why is the rightmost $0$ correct?

Comment: $0 \rightarrow H_1(D^2, S^1) \rightarrow \Bbb Z \rightarrow \Bbb Z \rightarrow 0$ is what it should be I see now, as $H_0(D^2) \approx \Bbb Z$.  Then $\ker (\Bbb Z \rightarrow \Bbb Z) = im(H_1(D^2, S^1) \rightarrow \Bbb Z) = 0 \Rightarrow H_1(D^2, S_1) = 0$.

Answer (score 4):

I usually use reduced homology to reduce confusion for lower homology groups.  The long exact sequence contains
$$\widetilde{H}_1(D^2)\to H_1(D^2,S^1)\to \widetilde{H}_0(S^1)$$
and since the reduced homology groups on either side are $0$, you have your result.

But, it is worth clearing up what is going wrong with your argument.  Let's not skip any of the zeroth homology groups.
$$H_1(D^2)\to H_1(D^2,S^1)\to H_0(S^1)\to H_0(D^2) \to H_0(D^2,S^1)$$
We know $H_0(S^1)$ and $H_0(D^2)$ are both $\mathbb{Z}$ since they each have exactly one connected component.  Also, $D^2$ is contractible so $H_1(D^2)=0$, hence the sequence is
$$0\to H_1(D^2,S^1)\to \mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}\to H_0(D^2,S^1)$$
The map $\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$ is the induced map from the inclusion $S^1\to D^2$, and it sends a generator to a generator, so it is an isomorphism (all we care about, though, is that it has no kernel).  Thus, $H_1(D^2,S^1)=0$.